# Phalcon 3.4: Inject a component in a controller action without using dispatcher events

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to use laravel way to inject a component in a controller action, see this example from laravel:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');

        //
    }
}
```

They use something called "service container" to resolve action params, is this applicable in Phalcon ?

I did try to make it manually but with no luck!

I need this functionality to avoid defining each component as a service in Phalcon DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a solution described in Phalcon docs, but with some tweaks to match my needs.

The solution I came with is to add new dispatch event listener to the servise container to handle the action depedencies, example:

```
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() {
    $evManager->attach("dispatch:beforeDispatch", function (Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
        try {
            $methodReflection = new ReflectionMethod(
                $dispatcher->getControllerClass(),
                $dispatcher->getActiveMethod()
            );
            foreach ($methodReflection->getParameters() as $parameter) {
                $parameterClass = $parameter->getClass();
                if ($parameterClass instanceof ReflectionClass) {
                    $dispatcher->setParam($parameter->name, new $parameterClass->name);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new \Exception('', Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    });
    $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($evManager);
    return $dispatcher;
}
```

Each framework has it's own mechanism, so if you need to make something special, you have to make it manually.